# Twitter4J on netbeans proyect not able to import jar file

Tags: twitter, netbeans, jar, twitter4j

I am learning to use twitter4J library, i was trying to add the jar (twitter4J-core-4.0.7-javadoc) file in my netbeans proyect, i already added it to the library in my proyect but within my source code, the imports are throwing a "package twitter4J doesnt exists" error, but i already added the jar file to my proyect, what am i doing wrong or what am i missing?

i added the twitter4J.properties to my src folder
also, i was wondering why are almost all the files within the jar file .html?

Comment: I like gradle for this but maven is probably more widely used.  Might I suggest trying either or both?  Worth your time to learn, it's not too complex.  Build files can be debugged.

Answer (score 0):

i already found the answer to my problem, the thing was, i was importing the twitter4J-core-4.0.7-javadoc.jar file within library but i didnt need this file but the twitter4J-core-4.0.7.jar found in the lib folder.